# Connecting 2 Monitors to Radeon HD 6450

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

i have a pretty old and slow PC with a build in Radeon HD 6450. I checked and there are 3 possible connections: HDMI, DVI-Sub, VGA (i hope i am correct here). I do have a very, very old (10+ years) monitor which i used to connect via an adapter to the VGA port. Now i want to add a second monitor - a Samsung SD390_S24D390HL.

I just get a blackscreen, neither Windows nor the AMD driver successfully find the 2nd monitor which i connected with a cable which is DVI-Sub i guess (definitely not HDMI). What could i be doing wrong here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you checked you have the correct DVI cable, there are several sub-standards for DVI? Does it work if you only connect that one monitor?

Comment: So your trying to use the VGA port and the DVI port?  That likely is the problem, its unlikely based on your hardware, that will be possible.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the HD6450 already came with a dedicated VGA port therefore you cannot convert the DVI to the second VGA monitor since the architecture of the PCB board will not allow to do so. You can either use VGA and HDMI or DVI and HDMI not VGA and DVI period.

[source](http://diamondmm.com/board/index.php?topic=439.0)